# Custom pane breaks checkout flow

Tags: commerce

I've successfully created a customizable custom field per [Commerce instructions](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane). This field holds welcome message markup that goes on my login page.

I have a setting that allows users who are already logged in to skip the login page and go straight to checkout. However, placing this field breaks the flow, so logged in users are now going to the login page, which shows the welcome message but no login field.

How can I keep the custom pane from hijacking my checkout flow?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a custom message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "my_checkout_pane_custom_message",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom message"),
 *   display_label = @Translation("great choice!"),
 *   default_step = "_sidebar",
 *   wrapper_element = "fieldset",
 * )
 * )
 */
class CustomMessagePane extends CheckoutPaneBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
  $pane_form['message'] = [
    '#markup' => $this->t('@custom_message', ['@custom_message' => $this->configuration['custom_message']]),
  ];
  return $pane_form;
}

public function defaultConfiguration() {
  return [
    'custom_message' => 'This is my custom message.',
  ] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
}

public function buildConfigurationSummary() {
  return $this->t('Custom message: @custom_message', ['@custom_message' => $this->configuration['custom_message']]);
}

public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
  $form['custom_message'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Custom message'),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['custom_message'],
  ];

  return $form;
}

public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

  if (!$form_state->getErrors()) {
    $values = $form_state->getValue($form['#parents']);
    $this->configuration['custom_message'] = $values['custom_message'];
  }
}
}
```